# How to read image with IIOImage and Get Raster

Tags: java, javax.imageio, raster

I am trying to read an image in Java and access the pixels via the raster.  However I get an NPE from the Raster, how do I access it?

Here is what I am doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    IIOImage iioImage = Image.readImage(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/annalisa-licciardi.png"));
    System.out.println(iioImage.getRaster().getHeight());
}
```

readImage is implemented as follows:

```
public static IIOImage readImage(ImageInputStream stream) throws IOException
{
    if (stream == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("stream == null!");

    Iterator iterator = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream);

    if (!iterator.hasNext())
        return null;

    ImageReader imageReader = (ImageReader) iterator.next();
    ImageReadParam param = imageReader.getDefaultReadParam();
    imageReader.setInput(stream,true,true);
    IIOImage iioImage = imageReader.readAll(0,param);
    stream.close();
    imageReader.dispose();
    return iioImage;
}

public static IIOImage readImage(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
{
    return readImage(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(inputStream));
}
```

How do I get the raster?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just loading a `BufferedImage` with `ImageIO`, then then obtaining the raster from that one? (Not sure whether there is a difference, just for clarification)

Comment: I have tried that but I do not know how to get the int rgba values.  Can you help me with that?  What am I doing wrong HERE: http://pastebin.com/LZK5HTpy

Comment: Again, there **may** be a simple solution: You could just call `bufferedImage.getRGB(x,y)` to obtain the ARGB value. (Using the raster may be faster, but you have to know exactly how the data is stored internally. The `getRGB` method does all necessary conversions internally for you)

Answer (score 1):

`ImageReader.readAll(...)` doesn't work that way.

Form the JavaDoc:

> Reads the image indexed by `imageIndex` and returns an `IIOImage` containing the image, thumbnails, and associated image metadata, using a supplied `ImageReadParam`.
>   The actual `BufferedImage` referenced by the returned `IIOImage` will be chosen using the algorithm defined by the `getDestination` method.

Also note that an `IIOImage` can only hold either a `BufferedImage` *or* a `Raster`. Not both. `readAll(...)` will return an `IIOImage` that holds a `BufferedImage`. So, basically, what you are trying to achieve won't work.

But as @Marco13 says in the comments, it's trivial to get the `Raster` from the `BufferedImage` once you have loaded it.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(input);
WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
```

To get the pixels as `int` ARGB values, you don't need the `Raster`, you can *always* get it from the `BufferedImage` directly:

```
int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
```

These values will be normalized and in the sRGB color space. And it will work, regardless of the actual sample format in the image.

However, if (and only if) your raster (or its backing `DataBuffer`, really) is already containing pixels in `int` ARGB (pixel packed) format, you can access them in this way, which is faster (as it requires no conversion):

```
int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

In many cases though, images will be in 3 or 4 `byte` RGB/BGR or RGBA/ABGR (pixel interleaved) form.

You can then get the pixels directly like this:

```
byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

You need to loop through the values and convert to `int` packed form, if that is what you prefer.